# HAProxy Frontend 'http-response return' Does Not Return Custom HTML For HTTPS

Tags: html, http, ssl, proxy, haproxy

I have an HAProxy configuration in which I have defined an ACL to block some IP addresses. I use this configuration to return a 403 as well as a custom HTML page.

The proxy works when I call HTTP and returns the HTML page.

[image]

But when I try to call an address via HTTPS using this proxy, it does not return the static content. (I have already set a subdomain pointing to this server)

[image]

I have tried using SSL for my subdomain but it was no use. Can someone explain the reason? I do appreciate it.

```
frontend myfront
  bind 0.0.0.0:8717
  http-request capture req.fhdr(User-Agent) len 1024
  acl blocked-ips src -f /etc/haproxy/blocked.ips
  http-response return status 403 content-type "text/html; charset=utf-8" file "/etc/haproxy/errors/not-allowed.html" if blocked-ips
  default_backend mybackend

backend mybackend
  balance roundrobin
  timeout server 300s
  server myserver <server_address>:<server_port> check inter 10s
```